# Prove $\frac{2n+\sin(n)}{n+2}$ converges to 2.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Here's my attempt.

Let $\epsilon >0.$ Then $N \geq \frac{5}{\epsilon}$, with $n \geq N \implies$

$| \frac{2n+\sin(n)}{n+2} -2|=| \frac{2n+\sin(n)-2n-4}{n+2}|=| \frac{\sin(n)-4}{n+2}|= \frac{|\sin(n)-4|}{n+2} \leq \frac{5}{n+2} \leq \frac{5}{n} \leq \epsilon$

Comment: I have nothing to add to what you wrote.

Comment: Good, good, good!

Comment: Thanks guys! I just wanted to make sure I dealt with the $\sin(n)$ right :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good job!

If you don't have to prove from definition:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n + \sin n}{n+2} = \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{2+ \frac{\sin(n)}{n}}{1+\frac{2}{n}}=2
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,
$$
\frac{2n-1}{n+2}
\le
\frac{2n+\sin(n)}{n+2}
\le
\frac{2n+1}{n+2}
$$
and both bounds go to $2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

$$\frac{2n+\sin n}{n+2}=2+\frac{\sin n-4}{n+2}$$

and the numerator of the fraction is bounded while the denominator increases to infinity.